# Comparing ThreeTen backport to JSR-310

Tags: java, java-time, jsr310, threetenbp

For some reasons, we can't use java 8 right now - we're still stuck at java 7.
However, I'd like to use the new `JSR-310 date/time APIs` right now,  using the [official backport ThreeTen](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Its homepage states:

```
The backport is NOT an implementation of JSR-310, as that would require 
jumping through lots of unnecessary hoops. Instead, this is a simple backport
intended to allow users to quickly use the JSR-310 API on Java SE 6 and 7.
```

**Questions:**

1. What are your **experience** with ThreeTen? Are there some drawbacks?
2. How **compatible** is this project compared to the official `JSR-310` implementations?
3. How much **effort** is required to **migrate** from ThreeTen to an **official java 8** implementation?
4. **Is it worth** to migrate now to ThreeTen and later to JSR-310 - or should someone wait until java 8 can be used, hencing skipping ThreeTen?

Comment: One thing you won't get is the brdidge from the Date API - for example in Java 8 you can write `new Date(...).toInstant()` but you won't have that in Java 7. This may or may not be an issue for your use case.

Comment: I guess answers to questions 3/4 would heavily depend on **how** you make use of Three Ten backport API. I guess: if you are careful; and try to understand the consequences of your actions; efforts for q3 should be minimal.

Comment: Use or Wait, or - third alternative - **JODA** date/time. As the old classes are best forgotten, date/time classes can be unittested, you may go for the backport + unit tests + unit tests under Java 8. That is easier, more pleasant than a later rewrite. On the other hand is it worthwhile?

Comment: @JoopEggen If they plan to move on to the new Java Time API at some stage, using threetenbp will make an easier transition than using Joda.

Comment: @assylias I agree, and a couple of unit tests should assure that functions do what one thought. However if Java 8 is more of an intention than pinned down, JODA might be a temporary solution.

Comment: ThreeTen has some issues with certain locales such as Korea. It crashes on startup. If you do not run in a lot of other countries this might not be a concern to you. Right now I am looking for a ThreeTen replacement due to the startup crash that keeps occurring with some of our international users. If they updated the locale table this would probably go away.

Answer (score 7):

See this [blog post](http://blog.joda.org/2014/07/threeten-backport-vs-joda-time.html).

ThreeTen-Backport is a solid backport consisting of equivalent code for the main API (though not so good for non-ISO calendar systems). To convert to Java 8 `java.time` requires changing the package name, and altering some constants to be method references.

I would not advise migrating from Joda-Time to ThreeTen-Backport, but do advise migrating from Joda-Time to Java 8 `java.time`.

Comment: Is it possible now to migrate to java.time?