# ThreeTen-Backport implementation vs. backport of JSR-310?

Tags: java, jsr310, threetenbp

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Comparing ThreeTen backport to JSR-310](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346649/comparing-threeten-backport-to-jsr-310).  My question is more specific.

In my company, I'm trying to get DevOps to O.K. the use of ThreeTen-Backport for refactoring legacy code (which because of deployment constraints with WebLogic 10.3.6.0 we can't upgrade from Java 6 and can't use any version of JodaTime beyond version 1.2.1).

I can see DevOps having an issue with this statement on ThreeTen-Backport's Github page:

> The backport is **NOT an implementation** of JSR-310, as that would
>   require jumping through lots of unnecessary hoops. Instead, this is a
>   simple backport intended to allow users to quickly use the JSR-310 API
>   on Java SE 6 and 7.

When they ask me what "Not an implementation" means, I need to be able to explain it to them.  However, the word *implementation* can have a wide semantic range, and I'm not sure exactly what is meant by that myself.

So my question is, in contexts like this, what is meant by *implementation* vs. *backport*?  Since JSR-310 is a backport and not an implementation, is there a counter example of something that I could use, that **is** an implementation of something else, in the same sense that ThreeTen-Backport is **not** an implementation of JSR-310?  What would an actual *implementation* of JSR-310 for Java 6 look like if such a thing existed, and how would it be different from ThreeTen-Backport?

Answer (score 4):

[*JSR 310: Date and Time API*](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) is a formal specification controlled by the [Java Community Process](https://jcp.org/en/home/index) (JCP) and with a whole heap of legalistic controls. An implementation of any JSR, including JSR-310, requires passing the [testing kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit) and other hurdles.

In the case of JSR-310, the JSR is *integrated into Java 8 itself*, which means that it simply is not possible to implement the JSR independently. There is no testing kit for JSR-310 outside the JDK. Thus no piece of code can implement JSR-310 outside the JDK itself.

Thus, [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) is as close to an implementation of the JSR-310 specification without actually being an implementation, where "implementation" is with reference to the *JSR-310 specification*.